# Looping error - game simulator not tracking wins and losses correctly

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a simple craps simulator for Java class and for some reason, it is having trouble running correctly. It is supposed to keep track of losses with "point" and wins with "point" but for some reason, those values tend to be 1 or 0 every time. The losses and wins on first roll seem to be working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class CrapsSimulator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set up values we will use
    int lossfirstroll = 0;
    int winfirstroll = 0;
    int losswithpoint = 0;
    int winwithpoint = 0;

    boolean gameover = false;
    int point = 0;

    // Loop through a craps game 100 times
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        
        // First roll -- random number within 2-12
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(11) + 2;

        // Win on first roll
        if (random == 7 || random == 11) {
            winfirstroll++;
            gameover = true;
        } // Loss on first roll
        else if (random == 2 || random == 3 || random == 12) {
            lossfirstroll++;
            gameover = true;
        } else // Player has "point"
        {
            point = random;
        }

        // Check to make sure the game hasn't ended already
        while (gameover == false) {
            // Reroll the dice
            random = rand.nextInt(11) + 2;

            // Check to see if player has won
            if (random == point) {
                winwithpoint++;
                gameover = true;
            }

            // Or if the player has lost
            if (random == 7) {
                losswithpoint++;
                gameover = true;
            }

            // Otherwise, keep playing
            gameover = false;
        }
    }

    // Output the final statistics
    System.out.println("Final Statistics\n");
    System.out.println("Games played: 100\n");
    System.out.println("Wins on first roll: " + winfirstroll + "\n");
    System.out.println("Losses on first roll: " + lossfirstroll + "\n");
    System.out.println("Wins with point: " + winwithpoint + "\n");
    System.out.println("Losses with point: " + losswithpoint + "\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd move the `new Random()` outside the for loop, just in case that's mucking with the entropy of the random numbers.

Comment: @darvids0n Good suggestion but it didn't help. I appreciate it though.

Answer (score 2):

either run it through a debugger, or sprinkle `System.out.println` and see where your logic is failing.  Is this homework?

Comment: The fact that the OP says he's writing the program `for Java class` should make that plain.

Comment: I'd also say, using a debugger should be first thing to do. Adding a breakpoint to the line "point = random" should make some things clear.

Comment: Yes. It's homework. But what difference does it make? I have all the source written. It's just snagging somewhere and I am turning to you guys for "fresh eyes" to maybe see the error I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `gameover` flag.  You are always settings it to `false` again at the end of the inner loop, this will make it run forever.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo I had from when I was debugging. Good eye though :)

Comment: I needed to set gameover to false at the beginning of the for loop. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, when coding, you probably wanted to set it to false at the end of the for loop instead of the end of the while loop.  It would have worked then. However, specifying it at the beginning of each iteration is cleaner.